# Can I cancel a friend request?

Tags: origin

I attempted to add a friend of mine to my Origin friends list through searching for their name. However, it seems that I accidentally invited the wrong person.

Is there any way to rescind/cancel the friend request I sent to the random person, or will I just have to wait for them to eventually accept/decline my request?

Comment: This is not reversible.  You should have read the EULA better.  You are now required to exchange phone numbers and invite this person over to watch TV on a regular basis.

Comment: @Origami Damn you, fine print, damn yooooou!

Comment: Also the channel is decided soley on the requestees taste. Good luck.

Comment: Is this really a gaming question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's not a way to do that. It is something people have been asking for on a few forums, but so far, it hasn't been implemented.

You will have to wait to see what the random person decides to do, and if they choose to friend you, you can always unfriend them by right-clicking their name in your list of contacts, and then clicking "unfriend".

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you will just have to wait for them to accept it and delete them, or deny it. This has been an issue that people have been trying to get added to Origin for a while. Origin, to be honest, is very horribly done...

Answer (score 1):

You can add them to "block list" it will automatically delete pending friend requests. To do so:

- Open your profile in Origin (click on your avatar in upper right corner)
- Click on "Edit my profile section"
- Go to privacy settings
- Add user names to the block list
- You can safely remove them from list after this, they will not appear in your pending friends anymore.

Comment: This may have worked at one time but it doesn't anymore. I followed these steps exactly over a week ago, and while all of my pending friends are on my block list, they're still pending friends. :(